# Dash Home really long to show up

Tags: unity-dash

when I click on the Dash Home button, the search boax application is really long to appear (around 5 seconds).
How to remedy this?

thanks
Ubuntu 12.10 (I don't really want to upgrade it, because the last time I had to fresh install..., so I am waiting for the next LTS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Recommend you Try Speeding Up Your Unity Interface by following these steps that i have posted in another thread:

To Speed Up Unity Follow Here:

1. Open A Terminal Window (CTRL T) Or Search Terminal In Unity
2. Type In The Following:

   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
3. Close Your Terminal
4. Goto Unity Search And Type In:

   Compiz
5. Click Compiz
6. First Click `Opengl Plugin`
7. **Take A Screenshot Before You Do Any Changes!!!**
8. Change The Following

   Uncheck Sync To VBlank And Change the Dash Blur To No Blur

   Then See if This Made Unity A bit Faster!
   If it made unity faster and you are satisfied, Close Compiz

**if Not you can try a couple other tweaks**

9. Click back At The Bottom Then Click Composite
10. Take Another Screenshot
11. Then Uncheck The Option `Detect Refresh Rate`
12. Then Click Back And Go Into Unity
13. Take Another Screenshot
14. Then Change The Following Option

    Change: Dash Blur To No Blur

**Then Close Compiz**

If there was an issue during your installation or you have problems with Unity or anything, Use the screenshots you took to restore your Settings.

Enjoy!

MY Thread were its originally posted:https://askubuntu.com/questions/385005/how-to-speed-up-the-whole-unity-interface

Tell me if this worked for you!

Comment: I gave it a day or two but the dash is still very slow...it's like the system is swapping the dash on the disk...

Comment: i recommend you use xubuntu instead. it uses an XFCE enviroment. www.xubuntu.org

Comment: indeed it seems that after a restart the dash is faster. Thank you!

Comment: Anytime!!! If you need any assistance. please dont hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to speedup this is to uncheck two thing-

goto system settings - privacy and uncheck both `including online search results` and `record activity`.As shown below [image: privacy]

It will definitely work.

Comment: oh, i misunderstood the question, i though his graphics slowed everything down. oh well. well said

Comment: its ok , the thing you have suggested is fine , even it works , but that too is not noticeable ..

Comment: Should i quote your answer?

Comment: added info to my answer on my guide thread

Comment: so i shoud remove it?

Comment: I am gonna try and test and get back to you

Comment: I did that...and the dash is still very slow

Comment: after making both off , do a restart ,, then see.

Comment: @Sushantp606 yes it seems that after a restart, the dash prompts faster... thanks